# Why is Permon data time format is reversing day and month when I open csv in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, perfmon

I have exported perfmon logs into csv.

I open the csv in excel, and the 1st column has the datetime value, so I right click on it and format to select the following custom format: dd-mmmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss

The output is:
05-May-2022  08:00:16
05-June-2022  08:00:16

I am expecting it to be: 05 May, 06 May. Why is this happening and what can be done to fix?

Sample CSV data:

```
"05/05/2022 09:22:12.301","0.00912"
"05/06/2022 07:45:03.341","0.00138"
```

Comment: Do not **open** CSV files. Rather **import** them using either Power Query or the legacy wizard.  When you do that you will be able tell Excel the format (eg: MDY) of the incoming data. If you do not do this, Excel assumes the incoming data is in the same format as your Windows regional setting. That may not always be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **From Text(Legacy)** feature to import the .csv to Excel and set the column format to **MDY**:
[image]

Then custom the cell format to *dd-mmmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss*:
[image]

Comment: Where is this feature `From Text(Legacy)`? In Excel?

Comment: What version of Office you're using? You can enable the Legacy data feature from File- Options- Data- under Show legacy data import wizards and check the From Text(Legacy):  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ7vE.png

Comment: Then go to Data- Get Data- Legacy Wizards: From Text(Legacy) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn92H.png

Comment: I tried this but it retains the mm/dd format and doesn't convert to dd/mm